# How to format a section heading in a manuscript

Tags: formatting

I am preparing a short story for submission.  As it is not a novel, there aren't chapters per se.  But there are definitely distinct sections.  Some of them might have titles, and/or associated quotes.  How should those be formatted?

I've been told that for sections without a title/quote to just put a "#" in the center of the line between sections.  What about when there is a title/quote?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Center the section heading and leave a blank line above and below it, like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Proin tortor purus platea sit eu id nisi litora libero. Neque vulputate consequat ac amet augue blandit maximus aliquet congue. Pharetra vestibulum posuere ornare faucibus fusce dictumst orci aenean eu facilisis ut volutpat commodo senectus purus himenaeos fames primis convallis nisi.
>
> Section heading
>
> Phasellus fermentum malesuada phasellus netus dictum aenean placerat egestas amet. Ornare taciti semper dolor tristique morbi. Sem leo tincidunt aliquet semper eu lectus scelerisque quis. Sagittis vivamus mollis nisi mollis enim fermentum laoreet.

Comment: Thats great. Thanks very much.